# How to merge multiple enumerations in XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

Can I combine multiple enumerations, taken from different *.xsd files into single enum like it is shown below?

First file content:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://module1namespace"
            xmlns:tns="http://module1namespace">
    <xsd:simpleType name="LocalEnum">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="LocalEnumValue1" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Second file content:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://module2namespace"
            xmlns:tns="http://module2namespace">
    <xsd:simpleType name="LocalEnum">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="LocalEnumValue2" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Merging file content:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://controllernamespace"
            xmlns:tns="http://controllernamespace">
   <xsd:import namespace="module1namespace" schemaLocation="pathToFirstXsd"/>
   <xsd:import namespace="module2namespace" schemaLocation="pathToSecondXsd"/>
....
</xsd:schema>
```

that is equal to :

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://controllernamespace"
            xmlns:tns="http://controllernamespace">
   <xsd:simpleType name="GlobalEnum">
     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="LocalEnumValue1" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="LocalEnumValue2" />
     </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can combine two enumerations via `xsd:union`.**

Here is a complete, working example, which also fixes the namespace declarations and references to be consistent:

### Main.xsd

<sub>Thanks to sergioFC for his good suggestion to use @memberTypes here, which is cleaner than having separate simpleType children to union:</sub>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://controllernamespace"
            xmlns:m1="http://module1namespace"
            xmlns:m2="http://module2namespace">

  <xsd:import namespace="http://module1namespace" schemaLocation="1.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://module2namespace" schemaLocation="2.xsd"/>

  <xsd:simpleType name="GlobalEnum">
    <xsd:union memberTypes="m1:LocalEnum m2:LocalEnum"/>
  </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

### 1.xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://module1namespace">
  <xsd:simpleType name="LocalEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="LocalEnumValue1" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

### 2.xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://module2namespace">
  <xsd:simpleType name="LocalEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="LocalEnumValue2" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunally in calss, which is dinamically generated from that main.xsd, GlobalEnum's type is string, not enumeration. Which means I have to hardcode those enum values in handlers. So is there a way to keep GlobalEnum content as <xsd:enumeration> or I have to deal with that code generator's feature ?

Comment: @kjhughes Note that union could be simplified to `<xsd:union memberTypes="m1:LocalEnum m2:LocalEnum"/>`